# How to properly dynamically change NuGet PackageId and dependency PackageId at build time?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard

We have an internal convention where if the CI/CD is doing a feature branch build, the NuGet package should be publish as "PackageId-FeatureBranchName". We publish these packages to a special feed that we don't reference in production builds.  In our build script, if we detect we are doing a feature branch build, we look for any .nuspec files output by the build and the build would replace in the .nuspec file "" with "-FeatureBranchName" in all .nuspec files in the solution.  This works fine if there is only one package with no dependencies on other projects in the solution.

Now I have two .NET Standard projects My.Assmebly.A and My.Assmebly.B that need to have their own NuGet packages.  B depends on A.  I am able to use the same build script above to set the  of each package correctly.  However, I am not sure of a solution to also update the .nuspec for package B to also update it's dependency on A to have the renamed My.Assmebly.A-FeatureBranchName.

Is there an easy way to script this. Or, I feel like I'm not doing this in the correct way with `dotnet pack` but I don't see any way to set package ids through command line or other, specifically when it comes to dependencies like this.  I do see the $id$ token you can setup and replace. But I'm not sure how to use this now that .NET Standard projects generate their own .nuspec during the build. Nor do I think this will work with my dependency situation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Assmebly.B</id>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.1">
        <dependency id="My.Assmebly.A" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Assmebly.B-FeatureBranchName</id>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.1">
        <dependency id="My.Assmebly.A-FeatureBranchName" version="1.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't change the name of the assembly. The correct thing to do is to add the branch name to the version number using the `version-suffix` parameter. This removes the need for you to search and edit any `.nuspec` files to force your naming convention.

You can pack your assembly by running:

```
dotnet pack --version-suffix [branchname]
```

replacing `[branchname]` with the correct value.

You library would be published as:

```
name: My.Assembly.A
version: 1.0.0-FeatureBranchName
```

If you add a `version-suffix` to your version then this will also cause the packages to be listed as `pre-release` in the nuget package manager.

You can also use `version-ranges` in your dependency list to always get a specific version.
See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards) for the official documentation.

But, in essence, you can define your dependency as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Assmebly.B</id>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.1">
        <dependency id="My.Assmebly.A" version="1.0.*" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Package B will now depend on the latest `My.Assembly.A` in your package feed. If you publish them together then they should (in theory) stay in sync.

Comment: We aren't renaming the assembly, just the NuGet package id. They don't have to match.  I am investigating using the approach you mention as that seems to be the built in way to do what we are doing which was one of the solutions I was looking for.

Comment: My bad. I meant to say `package id` :-(

Comment: @Dude0001 did you find a way to rename the package id in the dependencies of the nuspec file ? or did you end up doing as shown in the answer ?